# MySQL - Automatically update total hours difference based on two other datetime columns

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to automatically update a column, `totalHours` based on two other date times. I am aware that I can do this with a query DATEDIFF(), but I want to be able to do this automatically, if possible, a default expressions such as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` which are automatically maintained by the DB on create and on update.

(I tried putting the DATEDIFF() as an expression but that didn't work, not surprising)

[image]

Comment: What "automatically" means? Is it "when I read data from the table"? "When I write data to the table"? "Every night at 3am"?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in that part. I want the totalHours to be updated whenever there is a change in startDateTime or startEndTime.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `VIEW`, or a `VIRTUAL COLUMN` since the `totalHours` will make data redundancy if you store it right away.

### View

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW `tableview` AS SELECT 
*, 
DATE_DIFF(startEndTime, startDateTime) AS totalHours
FROM blabla
;
```

That way, you will have the `totalHours` always up-to-date without data redundancy. You can rename the current table (fi: to `blabla_table`) and create the `VIEW` with the current name of the table (fi: `blabla`). That way, you won't have to update all queries using the `TABLE` so they can now use the `VIEW`.

### Virtual column

```
totalHours DATE AS (DATE_DIFF(startEndTime, startDateTime))
```

See the doc at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html